# Without jQuery, how can javascript check that multiple ajax calls have been completed, and once they have, execute a piece of code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I already know how to do this in jQuery (and oh boy is it easy), but I am simply curious about how this can be done in basic javascript, without jQuery. After all, jQuery IS javascript, and anything that can be done in one, can be done in the other (and not at all as difficult as some people may think!)

Please, help satisfy my curiosity! I would like to learn the underlying concept~

A common scenario - a user does multiple ajax calls, and would like to execute a piece of code, only upon the completion of both calls. How can this be accomplished?

---

Here is a simple example of a common scenario. And here's what I've tried so far, (but hasn't worked). I know that the reason it doesn't work, is because in javascript, only one ajax call can be handled, at a time. So, what *is* the proper way to do this without jQuery?

```
//gets result html code, for a settings div inside a log panel
//this page also inserts some info into my database
//it has to run first and finish first before second ajax call, runs
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
else  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
xmlhttp.open("POST","/scripts/post_login_panel_actions.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("settings_button_activate=1&display_image_url="+encodeURIComponent(settings_display_picture_url));

//gets result html code, for the login panel inside of which, there is a settings div
//this has to run after, so that it can render the new stuff that was added to my database
var xmlhttp2;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
else xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp2.open("POST","/scripts/post_login_panel_actions.php",true);
xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp2.send("settings_refresh_login_panel=1");     

//after both calls have been completed, the new login panel should be rendered
//and then, the new settings-div should be rendered inside of the new login panel
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("login_panel").innerHTML=xmlhttp2.responseText;
        document.getElementById("login_panel_settings").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    }    }
```

---

**EDIT, after reading answers, comments, and trying to write some more code:**

lleaff's answer is the best and holy shit its really versatile and you can literally just copy paste it and it will just magically work, for different variables and scenarios. I've accepted it as the right answer.

But here is some bonus information to help out people who may stumble upon this page ... on my own, I came up with a second (more crude and stupid!) method of controlling **both**

1. order in which the two ajax calls get executed (in those special cases where call 1 really really needs to finish before call 2 begins
2. the final function call happens only when both ajax calls finish

The problem here, is that javascript isn't naturally designed to let you easily check for stuff like "fire action X when variable Y changes" - so it may be hard for some people to figure out how to use the answers where people tell you to "keep a global variable to keep track of what has finished".

**You can fire off a check, everytime onreadystatechange function realizes that .. the ready state has been changed.** The problem with my original implementation was that I'd only checked the ready state of ONE of the ajax calls.

**A more crude (but easy to understand!) solution**, hopefully, this will offer additional help to people viewing this topic:

```
//Declare your ajax variables~
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
else  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
var xmlhttp2;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
else xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

//Step 1 (first ajax call) code will begin executing here
xmlhttp.open("POST","/scripts/post_login_panel_actions.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("settings_button_activate=1&display_image_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("settings_display_picture_url").value));

//Step 2 (second ajax call) this function will be called ... later in the code!
function ajax_call_two() {
    xmlhttp2.open("POST","/scripts/post_login_panel_actions.php",true);
    xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp2.send("settings_refresh_login_panel=1");
    xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function()  { 
        if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200) {
            //when Step 2 is finished, Step 3 is called.
            stuff_to_do_after_all_ajax_calls_are_finished();    }    }   }  

//Step 3 (stuff_to_do_after_all_ajax_calls_are_finished. literally.) this function will be called ... later in the code!
function stuff_to_do_after_all_ajax_calls_are_finished() {
    document.getElementById("login_panel").innerHTML=xmlhttp2.responseText;
    document.getElementById("login_panel_settings").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    } 

//When Step 1 is finished, Step 2 is called.
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        ajax_call_two();    }    }
```

Comment: just add a global counter, increase it when you fire the request and decrease it when you get response, in your response callback, check if the counter decrease to 0, execute your piece of code.

Comment: to help people who are new to javascript and might be reading the comment above: "in your response callback" means "check the counter inside of onreadystatechange" ~!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just name the function you pass to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` and assign it to the `onreadystatechange` property of each of your requests.

Here's how I would generalize the solution to this problem:

```
function requestsAreComplete(requests) {
    return requests.every(function (request) {
        return request.readyState == 4;
    });
} 

function unsuccessfulRequests(requests) {
    var unsuccessful = requests.filter(function (request) {
         return request.status != 200;
    };
    return unsuccessful.length ? unsuccessful : null;
}

function onRequestsComplete(requests, callback) {   
    // Wrap callback into a function that checks for all requests completion     
    function sharedCallback() {
        if (requestsAreComplete(requests)) {
            callback(requests, unsuccessfulRequests(requests));
        }
    }

    // Assign the shared callback to each request's `onreadystatechange`
    requests.forEach(function (request) {
        request.onreadystatechange = sharedCallback;
    });
}
```

And you'd use it like that:

```
onRequestsComplete([xmlhttp, xmlhttp2], function(requests, unsuccessful) {
    if (unsuccessful) { return; } // Abort if some requests failed

    document.getElementById("login_panel").innerHTML=requests[1].responseText;
    document.getElementById("login_panel_settings").innerHTML=requests[0].responseText;
});
```

Comment: wow, all the edits you've done every few minutes, are really good~

sorry for not accepting your answer right away. I'm watching this page constantly, but I'm a little slow, and I'm testing this stuff out, as we speak~ you're very nice to be so patient. I'll accept the answer soon soon~ just testing things~

Comment: Heh, no problem. And yeah I thought it'd be better to offer a more general and reusable solution. Please tell me if anything doesn't work.

Comment: I tested your code a lot, it works like a charmmm, accepted your answer (but you forgot to add `);` at the end, by accident~! ) and using what I learned from your well-written reply, wrote my own code solution too, one that pertains to my situation in particular. Thanks so much!